# Why is plotting envfit result in ggplot result in disproportionate arrows compared to sites?

Tags: r, ggplot2, vegan

The title of my question might seem very obvious as there are many tuto and already solved questions about plotting metaMDS and envfit result in ggplot here. But actually I followed these previous posts/tuto and I am still getting weirdly very 'long' variable arrows, such long that my sites plot is totally 'masked' (see plot). I tried running this several time with scaling the arrows using ordiArrowMul() or without and still coming to the same. Can anyone help me spot where I did a mistake somewhere or what's the problem?

## here is what I have as data and the code:

My dataframe is very large and using dput makes a very large code so I upload it to a drive here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1wupRAxS9Q5Ht0IplbstY7-MrF_FoVolo?usp=share_link

```
#read data 
data <- read.csv('~/data.csv',row.names = 1) 

envi <- read.csv('~/env.csv',row.names = 1)

meta <- structure(list(SAMPLE_ID = c("MOLA_1-1_A", "MOLA_1-1_A", "MOLA_1-1_A", "MOLA_10-1_A", "MOLA_10-1_A", "MOLA_10-1_A", "MOLA_12-1_A", "MOLA_12-1_A", "MOLA_12-1_A", "MOLA_13-1_A", "MOLA_13-1_A", "MOLA_15-1_A", "MOLA_15-1_A", "MOLA_15-1_A", "MOLA_18-1_A", "MOLA_18-1_A", "MOLA_18-1_A", "MOLA_19-1_A", "MOLA_19-1_A", "MOLA_19-1_A", "MOLA_21-1_B", "MOLA_21-1_B", "MOLA_22-1_A", "MOLA_22-1_A", "MOLA_22-1_A", "MOLA_23-1_B", "MOLA_23-1_B", "MOLA_23-1_B", "MOLA_25-1_A", "MOLA_25-1_A", "MOLA_25-1_A", "MOLA_4-1_A", "MOLA_4-1_A", "MOLA_4-1_A", "MOLA_7-1_A", "MOLA_7-1_A", "MOLA_7-1_A", "MOLA_9-1_A", "MOLA_9-1_A", "MOLA_9-1_A"), `Month-Year` = structure(c(1556668800, 1556668800, 1556668800, 1590969600, 1590969600, 1590969600, 1593561600, 1593561600, 1593561600, 1596240000, 1596240000, 1604188800, 1604188800, 1604188800, 1612137600, 1612137600, 1612137600, 1614556800, 1614556800, 1614556800, 1617235200, 1617235200, 1619827200, 1619827200, 1619827200, 1625097600, 1625097600, 1625097600, 1564617600, 1564617600, 1564617600, 1559347200, 1559347200, 1559347200, 1569888000, 1569888000, 1569888000, 1577836800, 1577836800, 1577836800), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), season = c("Spring", "Spring", "Spring", "Summer", "Summer", "Summer", "Summer", "Summer", "Summer", "Summer", "Summer", "Autumn", "Autumn", "Autumn", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter", "Spring", "Spring", "Spring", "Spring", "Spring", "Spring", "Spring", "Spring", "Summer", "Summer", "Summer", "Summer", "Summer", "Summer", "Summer", "Summer", "Summer", "Autumn", "Autumn", "Autumn", "Winter", "Winter", "Winter"), Depth = c("5 m", "5 m", "5 m", "5 m", "5 m", "5 m", "5 m", "5 m", "5 m", "5 m", "5 m", "5 m", "5 m", "5 m", "5 m", "5 m", "5 m", "5 m", "5 m", "5 m", "5 m", "5 m", "5 m", "5 m", "5 m", "5 m", "5 m", "5 m", "5 m", "5 m", "5 m", "5 m", "5 m", "5 m", "5 m", "5 m", "5 m", "5 m", "5 m", "5 m"), month = c("May", "May", "May", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Aug", "Aug", "Nov", "Nov", "Nov", "Feb", "Feb", "Feb", "Mar", "Mar", "Mar", "Apr", "Apr", "May", "May", "May", "Jul", "Jul", "Jul", "Aug", "Aug", "Aug", "Jun", "Jun", "Jun", "Oct", "Oct", "Oct", "Jan", "Jan", "Jan")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -40L))

#nmds 
set.seed(123) 
nmds = metaMDS(as.matrix(data), distance = "bray")

#envfit 
set.seed(123) 
ef <- envfit(nmds, envi, permu = 999) 
ef

#plot 
plot(nmds, type = "t", display = "sites") 
plot(ef, p.max = 0.05)
```

so far, so good, the output is this and it is fine
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFYxW.png)

now trying to do a nice ggplot does not give the same result

```
#extract envfit arrows data and filter out non significant one 
en_coord_cont = as.data.frame(scores(ef, "vectors")) * ordiArrowMul(ef) 
en_coord_cont$pval <- ef[["vectors"]][["pvals"]]
en_coord_cont <- filter(en_coord_cont,pval<=0.05)

#extract nmds scores and associate to metadata 
data.scores = as.data.frame(scores(nmds)) 
temp <- cbind(data.scores,meta) 
temp$month <-  factor(temp$month, levels = month.abb)

#ggplot 
xx = ggplot(temp, aes(x = NMDS1, y = NMDS2)) + geom_point(size = 4, aes( shape = Depth,colour=month))+ coord_fixed() + theme(axis.text.y = element_text(colour = "black", size = 12, face = "bold"), axis.text.x = element_text(colour = "black", face = "bold", size = 12), legend.text = element_text(size = 12, face ="bold", colour ="black"), legend.position = "right", axis.title.y = element_text(face = "bold", size = 14), axis.title.x = element_text(face = "bold", size = 14, colour = "black"), legend.title = element_text(size = 14, colour = "black", face = "bold"), panel.background = element_blank(), panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = NA, size = 1.2), legend.key=element_blank()) + scale_colour_manual(values = c('blue4','blue','green4','green3','green'  ,'red4' ,'orangered','orange','yellow3','yellow')) +geom_vline(xintercept = 0,linetype = "dashed")+ geom_hline(yintercept = 0,linetype = "dashed")+geom_segment(aes(x = 0, y = 0, xend =NMDS1, yend = NMDS2), data = en_coord_cont, size =1, alpha = 0.5, colour = "grey30") +geom_text(data = en_coord_cont, aes(x = NMDS1, y = NMDS2), colour = "grey30", fontface = "bold", label = row.names(en_coord_cont))

xx
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtJWc.png)

Comment: `ordiArrowMul` scales arrows to fit the current open graphics window.  This gives correct scaling when you use it to add arrows to the current plot. However, if the current plot is something else, the scaling may be off. `ggplot()` does not use the graphics window, and the key question is: what was the open graphics window when you called `ordiArrowMul` for `ggplot()` use?

Comment: Hello @JariOksanen. Very sorry for my late reaction. I understand, I actually called ggplot.

Comment: ordiArrowMul works badly with ggplot which scales the graph *after* adding all layers. ordiArrowMul finds the multiplier to a graph which was scaled *before* adding arrows. There is no natural scaling of correlation arrows to ordination plot, but you must estimate your own multiplier. Alternatively you can try https://github.com/jarioksa/ggvegan2 which tries to do the scaling automatically.