# envfit with ggplot creates disproportionate arrows

Tags: r, ggplot2, vegan

I am trying to add envfit to my NMDS plot made in ggplot and I am having the same issue as [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74830070/why-is-plotting-envfit-result-in-ggplot-result-in-disproportionate-arrows-compar) where the arrows are too small (I wanted to comment on the post but I do not have enough reputation points). [image: see plot here]

Here is my code:

```
df = read.csv("df.csv", header = TRUE)
com = df[,10:11]   #where columns 10 and 11 are my NMDS scores
env = pc[,2:9]   #where columns 2:9 are my environmental variables
en = envfit(com, env, permutations = 9999, na.rm = TRUE)
en

en_coord_cont = as.data.frame(scores(en, "vectors")) * ordiArrowMul(en)
en_coord_cat = as.data.frame(scores(en, "factors")) * ordiArrowMul(en)

com$Cluster = pc$Cluster

gg = ggplot(data = com, aes(x = Axis1B, y = Axis2B)) + 
  geom_point(data = com, aes(colour = Cluster), size = 3, alpha = 0.5) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("#CBCBCB", "#616161", "#000000"))  + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = 0, y = 0, xend = Axis1B, yend = Axis2B), 
               data = en_coord_cont, size =1, alpha = 0.5, colour = "grey30") + geom_text(data = en_coord_cont, aes(x = Axis1B, y = Axis2B), colour = "grey30", fontface = "bold", label = row.names(en_coord_cont)) + 
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(), 
        panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, colour = "grey30"), 
        axis.text = element_text(size = 12), 
        legend.key = element_blank(), 
        legend.title = element_text(size = 14, face = "bold", colour = "black"),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 9, colour = "black"))

gg
```

I can increase the length of the arrows by multiplying by a larger integer in `en_coord_cont = as.data.frame(scores(en, "vectors")) * ordiArrowMul(en)` such as `en_coord_cont = as.data.frame(scores(en, "vectors")) * ordiArrowMul(en) * 2` but from my understanding the appropriate length of the arrows is kept in the 'ordiArrowMul(en)' so I don't want to just multiply by a random number to get longer arrows.

I installed ggvegan as recommended by the comment in the linked post but I can't seem to figure out how it works... Since I already have all the values and envfit info extracted, am I to use the autoplot() command? Can I take my plot (object 'gg' and directly input it into ggvegan? I apologize for my lack of understanding of the package and R generally...

Any help is appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`envfit` was written for standard `plot` and **ggplot2** graphics do not work with it. Function `envfit` currently returns the arrow multiplier for use with non-R graphics (such as ggplot2), but then you need to know how to use it. Github package https://github.com/jarioksa/ggvegan2 should work with envfit arrows.

Comment: Hi @Jari, I installed ggvegan as recommended but I can't seem to figure out how it works... Since I already have all the values and envfit info extracted, am I to use the autoplot() command? Can I take my plot (object 'gg' and directly input it into ggvegan?

Comment: I suggested using ggvegan2 (from that github address). It is not based on autoplot, but more configurable and allows adding ggplot elements. It also has option to directly add envfit elements.

Comment: Hi @Jari are you able to help with the commands / code for ggvegan envfit?